# Wifi Sniffer App Guidance

Tags: .net, gps, wifi

I am writing a WiFi connectivity/sniffer in .Net to be used as a self deploying tool from a USB stick. The intention is that it will scan for unsecured available networks and then try to connect to each one in turn and detmerine whether there is a login / proxy or whether directo connection to my arbitary website is possible. This is to build up a roaming list of hotspots (and thier long term availability) for a database I am planning to populate.

The intention is to distribute this tool to friends/friends of friends in order to build a local map of my area for publication on the web. I am still unsure of whether this would breach any legislation (reading up on that now) or be of any long term value.

It is more of a pet project to learn WiFi coding tech than anything else, but also to help my mates who have IPods/PSPs etc.

My queestion is: What's the best SDK for this bearing in mind I need GPS functionality too- is the Mobile Devices SDK the best to use?

Thanks,

MaS

Comment: Just so you're aware, using someone else's wireless network without their consent is of questionable legality, at least in the US.  You might want to check out this article from Wikipedia on "Legality of Piggybacking": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_piggybacking

Comment: Thanks for the Wiki ref Matt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mobile Devices SDK is good to use if you've got Windows Mobile devices to use; From the legality standpoint, that may vary on the jurisdiction you're in, but I believe it would be considered as unauthorised access in at least the UK, and as such would fall foul of the law (usual disclaimer applies here -- I am no lawyer, consult one if you want a real answer, I tend to err on the side of caution)

Comment: You're probably right, though as I said I would only access unauthorised access points and then only to piggyback their Internet connection, not for any malicious intent but then as you intimate...tell it to the judge! :) Ta. MaS

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a lawyer, nor do I play oen on TV.

As has been pointed out, piggybacking on random open networks can be considered "unauthorized access", and *can*, in some jurisdictions, be prosecuted as a form of theft.

HOWEVER, there are open networks that *explicitly grant* free access (as in speech, as well as beer). "Free WiFi" coffeeshops, anyone? If you're careful to only keep/publish these, even if you accidentally sniff out private ones, you *may* have a defense if it ever becomes a legal issue.

Comment: There's already a register of these available on my IPod Touch App 'Free WiFi' but not enough near where I live :) I guess I may have to make a morality/risk based descision - certainly with regard to open web publication.